# Shiny retrieve data from selectize renderedUI

Tags: r, shiny-server, shiny, selectize.js

I am trying to create a shiny app where I load data from a CSV, use data from the CSV to populate a selectize menu, let the user hit an action button, and send the data back to the sever where I can manipulate it. My issue currently is I cannot return any of the data that has been selected. The selectize list populates wonderfully, but from there I am unable to manipulate any of the results on the server.

I have attached some code snippets below.

Thank you for your time!

server.R:

```
output$singlefactor <- renderUI({
name<-name()
selectizeInput("sfactor", "Select Last Name:", name$last.name,multiple=T)})

select_text<-eventReactive(input$goButton,{
updateSelectizeInput(session, "sfactor", server =TRUE,selected=input$sfactor)
print(input$sfactor)})
```

ui.R

```
 tabPanel("Name Search",
       sidebarLayout(
         sidebarPanel(uiOutput("singlefactor"),
                      actionButton("goButton", "Search"))
```

Comment: What do you want `selected_text` to be when things are working?

Comment: Basically I would want selected_text to be a vector of all of selections that the shiny app user pulls from the UI "selectize". From there, I would use the vector of names the user selected on the server side to query some data and select records that matched. The matching records would then be displayed in the mainpanel on that page (essentially)

Comment: Does `select_text<-reactive({input$sfactor})` do the job?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't; I tried putting a print("hi") in front of the input$sfactor as well, and it never showed up in my console. I select a bunch of names and nothing happens

Comment: Shiny doesn't let me `print` from inside `shinyServer`, where `input$sfactor` exists. Try `output$test <- renderPrint(input$sfactor)` in server.R and `verbatimTextOutput('test')` in ui.R.

Comment: I was finally able to solve it using an eventReactive... I was trying to do the eventReactive and then do the data manipulations in a reactive; That workflow didn't work. I had to do everything in the event reactive, and then  I was able to render the output to the UI. Works as intended now!